# Primitive root modulo $2p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modules, totient-function, primitive-roots

**The question:** Let $a,p \in \Bbb N$,$ \ $ $p$ is an odd prime, $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. prove that:

1. if $a$ is odd, $a$ is primitive root modulo $2p$.
2. if $a$ is even, $a+p$ is primitive root modulo $2p$.

Thank you

Comment: $\phi(2p)=\phi(p)=p-1$.

Comment: This has been solved here already. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807795/odd-primitive-root-modulo-an-odd-prime).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, the answer there is a very good answer, but I need the second paragraph too (it is answering only the first question)...

Comment: For the second question, just use $$(a+p)^k\equiv a^k\mod p$$ for every positive integer $k$ and that $a+p$ is odd and finally the chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{First one:}$
Since,$\phi(2p)=p-1$.
So,First we prove that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{2p}$

But since $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ for a being odd.

The result follows immediately from chinese remainder theorem.

If $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod{2p}$ for smaller d.
Then, $2p \mid a^d-1 \implies p \mid a^d-1 \implies a^d \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ contradiction.

For the second one,

First we prove that $(a+p)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{2p}$

But since $(a+p)^{p-1} \equiv a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $(a+p)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ for $a+p$ being odd.

The result follows immediately from chinese remainder theorem.

If $(a+p)^d \equiv 1 \pmod{2p}$ for smaller d.
Then, $2p \mid (a+p)^d-1 \implies p \mid (a+p)^d-1  \implies p \mid a^{p-1}-1\implies a^d \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see in the comments, this part has been answered already. But, if you can, I really need the second one.

Comment: Edited and I think now it works.I messed up in the first attempt.

Comment: If $a$ is even then $a+p$ is odd and a primitive root mod $p$.

Comment: Why is $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod p$ a contradiction?

Comment: Since we assumed that a is a primitive root modulo p.(its given)

Comment: You're right.  I didn't read the question properly....Sorry.  But ... wow, I'm sorry/concerned no-one in the OPs class was able to answer it.